# Rails retrieve related data through a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Given, for example, a `Book` object, which has several `Tags` associated with it. I know that I can retrieve all tags of a book easily, but how could I retrieve all the tags for a collection of books. Like a cloud of tags, but only the tags in the books of the collection, not all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the tags by the `book_id`s that match the id's in the collection of books.

```
Tag.where(:book_id => book_collection.map(&:id))
```

Comment: Nice, but from the viewpoint of architecture which would be the best place to retrieve this data? Suppose I am retrieving the books in the index, better create a new instance variable that already carries the tags?

Comment: @CarlosPereira: I'm not sure what you are asking - can you post some code in your question to clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have a index view of books ok, that simply list the books:

<ul id="books" class="thumbnails">
   <% = render @books%>
</ul>

In the same view I want to display a tag cloud of these books, recovered in the controller / model of books.

My question is whether the best place to implement the routine you suggested is the index method of the controller, creating a new variable @tags and uses it in view or should create a specific method in the Tag model for example, devolving relationship tags a set of books received as parameter.

Comment: @CarlosPereira: You should have a `@tags` variable to use in your view regardless because of separation of concerns.  You might want to move the logic into your model if this were reused at other points in your application.  Otherwise, keeping a simple query like this in the controller is fine as long as the query doesn't change and become complex (at which point - put it in your model for easier unit testing).